# Problems with sample size in Fisher's exact test

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

I am trying to use fisher.test on a 2x6 contingency table in R. My contingency table looks like this:

```
       cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4   cat5  cat6
base1 167821 79362 74568 84034 137967 30795
base2 165699 86418 74307 82624 138054 28470
```

I have tried

```
fisher.test(contingencyTable)
```

but I get the error

```
Error in fisher.test(contingencyTable) : FEXACT error 40.
```

Out of workspace.

I looked this up and found that I can manually increase my workspace. However, as you can see from the following output, this only leads to a different error.

```
> fisher.test(contingencyTable,workspace = 2e7)
Error in fisher.test(contingencyTable, workspace = 20000000) : 
 FEXACT error 5.
The hash table key cannot be computed because the largest key
is larger than the largest representable int.
The algorithm cannot proceed.
Reduce the workspace size or use another algorithm.
> fisher.test(contingencyTable,workspace = 2e6)
Error in fisher.test(contingencyTable, workspace = 2000000) : 
  FEXACT error 40.
Out of workspace.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this problem?

**EDIT**:
I was able to get rid of this problem by setting `simulate.p.value=T` in the fisher.test function -- this defaults to a chisq.test if the fisher test can not be computed due to large sample size. However, I nam notw running into the problem that my sample size is too large so all variables are being considered significantly different, as whuber noted.

Is there some adjustment I could make to the p value so that it would remain meaningful for any sample size? I am thinking something similar to Bonferroni's adjustment.

Comment: With counts this large *any* test will tell you there is a "significant" difference. For instance, apply a chi-squared test. The underlying question is *why do you want to do this*? What is the objective of your analysis?

Comment: the objective is as follows: I have two data sets that each have several categorical variables in common, though possibly different distributions. I know that they are different in some way (say they are the output of some unsupervised clustering algorithm), but I don't know whether this difference would also be reflected in any of their categorical variables. Therefore I want to go through each shared categorical variable and test whether they have the same distribution in the two data sets. so the test is purely descriptive -- not predictive in any way.

Comment: also, you are correct that both the fisher test and the chi-squared test are saying that the two sets are significant;y different. Any idea how I might get around this problem?

Comment: I don't understand why it's a problem at all.  The distributions from which `base1` and `base2` have been sampled are different.  Isn't that what you were looking for?  If by "this problem" you're referring to being unable to conduct the Fisher test, that's easily solved: use a chi-squared test.  They both give the same results with datasets this large.

Comment: but I actually don't klnow if the distributions are different in any particular categorical variable. all I know is that some of the variables are distributed differently. For example, you have a bunch of people separated into two groups based on some trait, but you don't know which trait. You have a set of traits for each group, and you want to determine which one is significantly different in order to get a sense of what the rule was. So you don't know a priori that any variable has a different distribution, just that one or some of them does.

Comment: This is morphing into quite a different question than you have posted: it's starting to sound like some kind of unsupervised learning or classification problem--or possibly just an ANOVA.  It's hard to tell, given the abstraction of the current formulation. Consider editing your post to reflect the kinds of data you actually have and the problem you really want solved.

Comment: the probolem is still the same: for any given categorical variable in both of the two data sets, I do not know if they are significantly different. I want to know if the two distributions are significantly different. true the obstacle I am now facing is different, but caused by the same thing: large sample size

Comment: Large sample size is not the problem.  It virtually *guarantees* statistical significance. The problem here is that significance is probably not relevant, because it merely reflects the fact you have enough data to detect differences that are likely inconsequential to you. That's why it is important to get beyond significance and think about why you're doing this and what you really want to learn. We can help with that part--but first we have to know what you're really trying to do!

Comment: Other than what I have already explained, what else can I elaborate on what I am trying to do? I have tried to explain in several precise ways so far. Also, as you yourself explained, large sample size is the problem -- not because it gives innacurate significance levels, but because it renders statistical significance an invalid metric. If there were some adjustment to the p value (I am thinking something like the Bonferroni adjustment), it would ideally account for the effects of sample size on significance.

Comment: That being said, I do think the title is no longer accurate, so I will edit it accordingly